# kknn classification: how to determine the value of kmax?

Tags: r, classification, knn

How can I determine the value of kmax to use? When I eliminate it, R prints an error message and when I add it, R prints another error message.  I keep going around and around with this not getting anywhere.  These messages are confusing.  I looked on stackoverflow for similar questions but did not see one, hence this question.  Do you know why kmax = 7 incorrect? How do I know what is the correct value of kmax?  Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
#works
output1 <- train.kknn( as.factor(myParam)~., data <- trainingData)
output1

#works
output1 <- train.kknn( as.factor(myParam)~., data <- trainingData, distance <- 2)
output1

# does not work
#error message: Error in train.kknn(as.factor(myParam) ~ ., data <- trainingData, kmax <- 7,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 9)
In addition: Warning message:
In train.kknn(as.factor(myParam) ~ ., data <- trainingData, kmax <- 7,  :  
NAs introduced by coercion

output1 <- train.kknn( as.factor(myParam)~.,  data <- trainingData, kmax <- 7, distance <- 2,kernel <- "rectangular")
output1


# does not work, 
# error message: Error in kmax + 2L : non-numeric argument to binary operator

output1 <- train.kknn( as.factor(myParam)~., data <- trainingData,  distance <- 2, kernel <- "rectangular")
output1
```

I need this to work:

```
output1 <- train.kknn( as.factor(myParam)~.,  data <- trainingData,
                     kmax <- ???,    <-  whatever this value should be
                     distance <- 2, kernel <- "rectangular")
output1
```

Comment: KNN needs all numeric (not factor, dummy, indicator, etc) variables. At a minimum, that is what your latest message is indicating.

Comment: you are right, I guess that is why the coercion is occurring.  Thank you for helping me see this.

Comment: How do I mark your comment as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

lmo's response was the answer  Thank you lmo for helping me see the light.